# How do you use a template literal in a match RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to use a variable in a RegEx and I’m having problems. This is my function:

```
const truncateNum = (num, place = 2) => {
  const matcher = `/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,${place}})?/`;
  const re = new RegExp(matcher);
  return num.toString().match(re)[0];
};
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem lies in meta character escaping. Place this `^\\-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,${place}})?` in your template literal to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

The first is that when you define a regex as a string, it doesn't require `//` marks, and also backslashes need to be double escaped `\\d+`.

The second is that `num.toString().match(re)` will return `null` if the regular expression doesn't match, thus you are getting an exception from trying to do an array lookup on `null[0]`.

```
let truncateNum = (num, place = 2) => {
  const  matcher = `^-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,${place}})?`; console.log(matcher);
  const  re      = new RegExp(matcher);
  const  match   = num.toString().match(re);
  const  result  = match && match[0] || '0'
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the solution!